# 64-bit Advantages for Discrete Event Simulation

Tags: simulation, simulator

As I understand it, Intel 64-bit CPUs offer the ability to address a larger address space (>4GB), which is useful for a large simulation.  [Interesting architectural hardware advantages:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/607322/what-are-the-advantages-of-a-64-bit-processor):

- 16 general purpose registers instead of 8
- Additional SSE registers
- A no execute (NX) bit to prevent buffer overrun attacks

## BACKGROUND

Historically, the simulations have been performed on 32-bit IA (Intel Architecture) systems.  I am wondering if where (if any) is opportunity to reduce simulation times with 64-bit CPUs: I expect that software should be recompiled to take advantage of 64-bit capability. This type of simulation would not benefit from a MAC (multiply and accumulate) nor does it use floating point calculations.

## QUESTION

That being said, is there an Intel 64-bit instruction or capability that offers an appreciable advantage over the 32-bit instructions set that would accelerate simulation (computationally intensive and lengthy 32-BIT algorithms)?

If you have experience implementing simulations and have transitioned from 32 to 64 bit CPUs, please state this in your response (relevant experience is important).  I look forward to insightful responses from the community

Answer (score 1):

The most immediate computational benefits to expect regarding CPU instructions I can think of would be [AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) although this is only loosely related to x86_64, but more of an CPU-generational issue.
In our company, we developed multiple, highly-complex discrete event simulations, simulating aircraft (including electrics, hydraulics, avionics software and everything related). They are all built with or ported to x86_64. The reasons are mostly due to memory addressing, allowing for larger caches and wider choice of algorithms (e.g. data-centric design, concurrency), graphics content also tends to be huge nowadays. However, optimizations regarding x86_64 instructions themselves, such as AVX, are left to compilers. I never saw code written in assembler or using compiler intrinsics to actually refer to specific x86_64 instructions explicitly.

To summarize, based on my experience, x86_64 CPUs allow for certain optimizations, often sacrificing memory consumption in favor of CPU processing:

- Wider choice of algorithms, especially regarding concurrency, where data may need to be laid out in a way favoring parallel processing at the cost of occupied memory
- Intermediate results or other processing output may be cached more easily in memory to avoid recomputation or to optimize for temporal or state-related coherence
- AVX instructions may help compilers to vectorize more code than with MMX/SSE